# how to query select data from table where first 3 character defined

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008

i want to filter dropdownlist by first 3 charater on job code, this is my query

```
string result3 = Checked_By.ToString().Substring(0, 3);


SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(" SELECT [Kode], [Nama] 
FROM [Job] WHERE LEFT(Kode, = '" + result3 + "') ORDER BY 
Nama ASC", con);

 SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
 DataTable dt = new DataTable();
 con.Open();
 sda.Fill(dt);
 con.Close();
```

Comment: SQL `LEFT` function takes 2 parameter, a string and a number. `LEFT('abcdef', 3)` returns `abc`. Side note. use `@parameter` even for 3 character string.

Comment: can give example, im not clear how to do.  SELECT [Kode], [Nama] 
FROM [Job] WHERE LEFT(Kode, '" + result3 + "', 3) .... like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is straightforward fix. First, fix SQL syntax error (SQL `LEFT` function takes 2 parameter, a string and a number. `LEFT('abcdef', 3)` returns `abc`), next rewrite using parameters. Something like this.

```
string result3 = Checked_By.ToString().Substring(0, 3);

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(" SELECT [Kode], [Nama] FROM [Job] WHERE LEFT(Kode, 3) = @result3 ORDER BY Nama", con); //ASC is OK but not required as it is default option
cmd.Parameters.Add("@result3", SqlDbType.Char, 3).Value = result3;

 SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
 DataTable dt = new DataTable();
 //con.Open(); //not necessary. SqlDataAdapter.Fill opens connection if it needs
 sda.Fill(dt);
 //con.Close(); //and closed if it wasn't open before .Fill
```

Comment: alex, can you help me? hot to get just c character from abcdef ? LEFT('abcedf',1,3) ??

Comment: use `select SUBSTRING('abcdef',3,1)`

Answer (score 0):

"SELECT [Kode], [Nama] 
FROM [Job] WHERE SUBSTR(Kode,1,3) = '" + result3 + "' ORDER BY 
Nama ASC"